# Solve the differential equation $(3x^2-2y-y^2)dx-(2x+3xy^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve the differential equation $(3x^2-2y-y^2)dx-(2x+3xy^2)dy=0$

My try:

We can write the equation as:

$$d(x^3)-2d(xy)=y^2dx+3xy^2dy$$

$$d(x^3)-2d(xy)=d(xy^3)+(y^2-y^3)dx$$

How can we proceed here?